# Flange is 2 inches below flooring level. Help!

Tags: flooring, toilet, flange, leaking

We have two toilets that are leaking because the flange is about 2 inches lower than the flooring. A plumber came out and put in three wax seals on each toilet, but it is still leaking. I asked the plumber to come back out and to give another bid to fix it and he wants $3200 to remove the concrete and put in a new flange. That is outrageous to me and I cannot begin to pay that. He says that the toilet will shift slightly and break any seal if we try to use an extender. Can anyone help me come up with a solution ?

Comment: any pictures of how it looks?

Comment: An extender if done right should not cause problems.

Comment: Unfortunately, the home is in another state so I don’t have any pictures. My parents live in the home. Not being close definitely complicates things.

Comment: If we use an extender and there is movement on the toilet, will it be OK? Is there a kind you would recommend?

Comment: it would depend on in what stage it is but so far I did not see any toilet to move to such an extent breaking the extender. it's not like you have that toilet on the wheels tho $3200 is totally a scam for an unnecessary fix

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: There are stock replacement flanges that extend into the pipe and seal, and **are bolted to the floor.** Using proper screws and anchors for concrete, those won't be moving. Example, not endorsement - Oatey Twist-N-Set available in both 3 and 4 inch diameter $26 bucks each, plus anchors and (please, use stainless steel or brass) screws. Maybe a masonry bit to install the anchors, perhaps a hammer drill to run the bit, still way ahead of $3200.

Comment: You can get a toilet flange extender kit; this one only goes up to 1-5/8", but that might be close enough to get you within nonleaking range: https://www.oatey.com/products/oatey-setrite-toilet-flange-extension-kits-448029873

Comment: Pricing is _explicitly_ off-topic because it can vary so much. I'd strongly recommend getting another couple of plumbers in to give quotes to fix it. Even if breaking the concrete & replacing piping is the only option, you may get a lower quote. You may also get much easier solutions like installing an extender. Of course, without pics, we cannot tell what condition the pipes in the concrete are in, and a full replacement _might_ be the only option that will last more than a year.

Answer (score 1):

Take 2 inch plywood, or two 1 inch plywood

Cut it in a circle (so it looks like doughnut) and it fits over the toilet drain.

Screw it in the concrete floor with concrete screws, you need 3 screws, but make sure they are not in the way of toilet ring mounts.

Screw in the toilet mount ring in place followed by wax seal.

You might need a toilet drain pipe extender that could look like this to bring the drain pipe closer to the toilet.

High Strength Toilet Waste Extension Pipe Internal And External ...
toilet-fittings.com

[image: extender]

Comment: If the existing flange is already below the floor, how is raising the floor going to help fix the problem? Won't that simply _increase_ the distance that needs to be spanned by some sort of new piping/extension/whatever?